# How to process an extremely large JSON request (1 GB+) to API with NodeJS and Express

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have written an API that accepts JSON post requests (list of objects) at an endpoint, interfaces with a KDB/Q database and returns a JSON response. It works very well until the requests start to get very large and have many rows of data (the database is still processing results extremely quickly). The server seems to run out of memory/crash when accepting such large POST requests of 100k+ objects in the list. Is there a way to accept a POST of this amount of data and return it in chunks?

Comment: You will need to parse the JSON incrementally as it arrives, processing each row as you can so you don't keep much in memory at a time.  Probably want to investigate one of the JSON stream parsers.  FYI, this sounds a bit like a reliability nightmare.  What if you get half way through a 1GB set of JSON, with much of it already added to the database and the http connection drops?

Comment: It might be easier to restrict POSTs to a number of objects that you comfortably all fit in memory at once on the server.  Then, you can receive the whole set of data first and reliably crunch on it on the server and the client can better know what was processed.  If you get disconnected before getting all the data, none of it gets processed rather than some of it.  The client would then have to do large uploads in multiple requests.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'll look into those JSON stream parsers. I am not adding any of the data to the database, it's more of a query as we perform some analytics on each row of data with Q (which uses the KDB database) and returns the results. So, I think reliability should be fine from the server side if the clients connection drops midway.

Comment: Yeah, I think that the server will work just fine if they split up their large requests to multiple smaller ones but they want to be able to just throw a large file/request and receive the results.